# Compute mean and standard deviation by group for multiple variables in a data.frame

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, reshape2

**Edit** -- This question was originally titled << Long to wide data reshaping in R >>

---

I'm just learning R and trying to find ways to apply it to help out others in my life. As a test case, I'm working on reshaping some data, and I'm having trouble following the examples I've found online. What I'm starting with looks like this:

```
ID  Obs 1   Obs 2   Obs 3
1   43      48      37
1   27      29      22
1   36      32      40
2   33      38      36
2   29      32      27
2   32      31      35
2   25      28      24
3   45      47      42
3   38      40      36
```

And what I want to end up with will look like this:

```
ID  Obs 1 mean  Obs 1 std dev   Obs 2 mean  Obs 2 std dev
1   x           x               x           x
2   x           x               x           x
3   x           x               x           x
```

And so forth. What I'm unsure of is whether I need additional information in my long-form data, or what. I imagine that the math part (finding the mean and standard deviations) will be the easy part, but I haven't been able to find a way that seems to work to reshape the data correctly to start in on that process.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Just a comment: I don't think that's what folks usually mean by moving from long to wide format.

Comment: Plenty have commented, but I am surprised no one cared to fix such a misleading title (now done.)

Answer (score 38):

This is an aggregation problem, not a reshaping problem as the question originally suggested -- we wish to aggregate each column into a mean and standard deviation by ID.  There are many packages that handle such problems.  In the base of R it can be done using `aggregate` like this (assuming `DF` is the input data frame):

```
ag <- aggregate(. ~ ID, DF, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

*Note 1:* A commenter pointed out that `ag` is a data frame for which some columns are matrices.  Although initially that may seem strange, in fact it simplifies access.  `ag` has the same number of columns as the input `DF`.  Its first column `ag[[1]]` is `ID` and the ith column of the remainder `ag[[i+1]]` (or equivalanetly `ag[-1][[i]]`) is the matrix of statistics for the ith input observation column.  If one wishes to access the jth statistic of the ith observation it is therefore `ag[[i+1]][, j]` which can also be written as `ag[-1][[i]][, j]` .

On the other hand, suppose there are `k` statistic columns for each observation in the input (where k=2 in the question).  Then if we flatten the output then to access the jth statistic of the ith observation column we must use the more complex `ag[[k*(i-1)+j+1]]` or equivalently `ag[-1][[k*(i-1)+j]]` .

For example, compare the simplicity of the first expression vs. the second:

```
ag[-1][[2]]
##        mean      sd
## [1,] 36.333 10.2144
## [2,] 32.250  4.1932
## [3,] 43.500  4.9497

ag_flat <- do.call("data.frame", ag) # flatten
ag_flat[-1][, 2 * (2-1) + 1:2]
##   Obs_2.mean Obs_2.sd
## 1     36.333  10.2144
## 2     32.250   4.1932
## 3     43.500   4.9497
```

**Note 2:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "ID  Obs_1   Obs_2   Obs_3
1   43      48      37
1   27      29      22
1   36      32      40
2   33      38      36
2   29      32      27
2   32      31      35
2   25      28      24
3   45      47      42
3   38      40      36"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Perhaps important to note: While the output of this will appear to be a `data.frame` with two columns for each column being aggregated (resulting in 7 columns with your example data), if you view the structure, you'll see that it is actually just four columns, with the aggregated columns being *matrices*. You can fix that with a `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ ID, DF, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))`.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, Good point. I have added some comemnts elaborating on this.

Answer (score 23):

There are a few different ways to go about it.  `reshape2` is a helpful package. 
Personally, I like using `data.table`

Below is a step-by-step

If `myDF` is your `data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(myDF)

DT

# this will get you your mean and SD's for each column
DT[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))]

# adding a `by` argument will give you the groupings
DT[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))), by=ID]

# If you would like to round the values: 
DT[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=round(mean(x), 3), sd=round(sd(x), 3))), by=ID]

# If we want to add names to the columns 
wide <- setnames(DT[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=round(mean(x), 3), sd=round(sd(x), 3))), by=ID], c("ID", sapply(names(DT)[-1], paste0, c(".men", ".SD"))))

wide

   ID Obs.1.men Obs.1.SD Obs.2.men Obs.2.SD Obs.3.men Obs.3.SD
1:  1    35.333    8.021    36.333   10.214      33.0    9.644
2:  2    29.750    3.594    32.250    4.193      30.5    5.916
3:  3    41.500    4.950    43.500    4.950      39.0    4.243
```

---

Also, this may or may not be helpful

```
> DT[, sapply(.SD, summary), .SDcols=names(DT)[-1]]
        Obs.1 Obs.2 Obs.3
Min.    25.00 28.00 22.00
1st Qu. 29.00 31.00 27.00
Median  33.00 32.00 36.00
Mean    34.22 36.11 33.22
3rd Qu. 38.00 40.00 37.00
Max.    45.00 48.00 42.00
```

Comment: I tried this and got 

`Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.`

Traceback showed that the problem was with the form of the call to `sapply`.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same method grouping by multiple factors? For example, by=c("ID", "factor2")?

Answer (score 18):

Here is probably the simplest way to go about it (with a [reproducible example](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Reproducibility)):

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3, 3), Obs_1=rnorm(9), Obs_2=rnorm(9), Obs_3=rnorm(9))
ddply(df, .(ID), summarize, Obs_1_mean=mean(Obs_1), Obs_1_std_dev=sd(Obs_1),
  Obs_2_mean=mean(Obs_2), Obs_2_std_dev=sd(Obs_2))

   ID  Obs_1_mean Obs_1_std_dev  Obs_2_mean Obs_2_std_dev
1  1 -0.13994642     0.8258445 -0.15186380     0.4251405
2  2  1.49982393     0.2282299  0.50816036     0.5812907
3  3 -0.09269806     0.6115075 -0.01943867     1.3348792
```

EDIT: The following approach saves you a lot of typing when dealing with many columns.

```
ddply(df, .(ID), colwise(mean))

  ID      Obs_1      Obs_2      Obs_3
1  1 -0.3748831  0.1787371  1.0749142
2  2 -1.0363973  0.0157575 -0.8826969
3  3  1.0721708 -1.1339571 -0.5983944

ddply(df, .(ID), colwise(sd))

  ID     Obs_1     Obs_2     Obs_3
1  1 0.8732498 0.4853133 0.5945867
2  2 0.2978193 1.0451626 0.5235572
3  3 0.4796820 0.7563216 1.4404602
```

Comment: There's one more observation you missed out. While this is the way to go with fewer columns, I think it gets ugly very quickly.

Comment: can we calculate mean of rows using this method ?

Answer (score 14):

I add the `dplyr` solution.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3, 3), Obs_1=rnorm(9), Obs_2=rnorm(9), Obs_3=rnorm(9))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd))

#      ID Obs_1_mean Obs_2_mean Obs_3_mean  Obs_1_sd  Obs_2_sd  Obs_3_sd
#   (int)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
# 1     1  0.4854187 -0.3238542  0.7410611 1.1108687 0.2885969 0.1067961
# 2     2  0.4171586 -0.2397030  0.2041125 0.2875411 1.8732682 0.3438338
# 3     3 -0.3601052  0.8195368 -0.4087233 0.8105370 0.3829833 1.4705692
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another take on the `data.table` answers, using @Carson's data, that's a bit more readable (and also a little faster, because of using `lapply` instead of `sapply`):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt = data.table(ID=c(1:3), Obs_1=rnorm(9), Obs_2=rnorm(9), Obs_3=rnorm(9))

dt[, c(mean = lapply(.SD, mean), sd = lapply(.SD, sd)), by = ID]
#   ID mean.Obs_1 mean.Obs_2 mean.Obs_3  sd.Obs_1  sd.Obs_2  sd.Obs_3
#1:  1  0.4854187 -0.3238542  0.7410611 1.1108687 0.2885969 0.1067961
#2:  2  0.4171586 -0.2397030  0.2041125 0.2875411 1.8732682 0.3438338
#3:  3 -0.3601052  0.8195368 -0.4087233 0.8105370 0.3829833 1.4705692
```

Comment: the second one should use `sd` and you use `.SD` twice.. is there a performance issue due to that? any idea?

Comment: @Arun, thanks, fixed the `sd` bit. I don't know if there is a performance hit because of that, let me check

Comment: @Arun looks like there is an ~10% performance hit, but the good news is that it doesn't increase with more categories

Comment: Also you'll see a optimisation message about creating names (mean, sd) for every `by` (which will be inefficient for huge data. I'm benchmarking on a 1e6 data.table. Will post the results shortly.

Comment: This works for me, however the resulting columns all have the same name, i.e. ```Obs_1```,```Obs_2```,```Obs_3```,```Obs_1```,```Obs_2```,```Obs_3```. not ```mean.Obs_1```... any ideas why that is the case?

Answer (score 3):

The updated dplyr solution, as for 2020

1: `summarise_each_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
and
2: `funs()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0.

```
ag.dplyr <- DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(.cols = everything(),list(mean = mean, sd = sd)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful function in the `psych` package.

You should try the following implementation:

```
psych::describeBy(data$dependentvariable, group = data$groupingvariable)
```